# Check if element hasClass(), if not, remove child

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-cycle

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbymac/pKZ9U/

This is using the jQuery Cycle plugin... What it's doing is, as you hover over each list item, the slide is changed and its corresponding list item has the class `activeSlide` added. What I'm trying to do is append HTML to the list item with the `activeSlide` class, and remove it when when the next list item is hovered over.

This code almost works. It appends my HTML to the `activeSlide` on load, but when I hover over the next list item, nothing changes. In the fiddle, you'll see that "Title 1" with the black background stays even when the slide changes.

Basically, I'm wondering how to check if an element has a class, and if it does, append something. If the class no longer applies, remove what was appended.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var titles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"];
    $("#slideshow").before("<ul id='slideshow-nav'></ul>")
    .cycle( {
        fx:                         "scrollVert",
        rev:                        "scrollVert",
        speed:                      600,
        timeout:                    0,
        pagerEvent:                 "mouseover", 
        pager:                      "#slideshow-nav",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {
            return "<li>" + titles[index] + "</li>";
        }
    });
    if($("#slideshow-nav li").hasClass("activeSlide")) {
        var ind = $("#slideshow-nav li").index();
        $("#slideshow-nav li.activeSlide").append("<a href='#'>" + titles[ind] + "</a>");
    } else {
        if($("#slideshow-nav li:not(.activeSlide)")) {
            $("a").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Uhm, where exactly are the event handlers for the mouse events? Or is that the issue, no event handlers == no events!

Comment: The event handlers are in the cycle code up above: `pagerEvent:                 "mouseover"`

Comment: But how would that execute the code in your condition ?

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. The mouse events are irrelevant since the HTML should be appended/removed depending on which list item has the `activeSlide` class. The plugin is already handling the mouse events.

Comment: @adeneo is correct - Even though jquery-cycle has a mouseover event handler to do its own thing, your check for .hasClass("activeSlide") is only firing once on document ready as it is not in an event handler of its own.

Comment: How do I make it continue to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @bbird, your if-statements execute only one.

Perhaps you can use the `onPagerEvent` callback to add and remove the `<a>` tag to the active list item.

First add the following function:

```
function activateItem(index) {
    $('#slideshow-nav').children('li').each(function (i) {
        var $item = $(this);
        if (i == index) {
            if ($item.children('a').length == 0) {
                $item.append('<a href="#">' + titles[i] + '</a>');
            }
        } else {
            $item.children('a').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it once at the start:

```
activateItem(0);
```

And in the `onPagerEvent` callback:

```
    onPagerEvent: function (index) {
        activateItem(index);
    }
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/pKZ9U/5/)

**Edit:** Updated the if-statement in the `activateItem()` function so the `<a>` element is appended to the list item's content, rather than replaces it.

Comment: A good solution, but I don't want the <a> tag to replace the content of each list item, just be appended. Swapping the `.html()` in this line `$item.html('<a href="#">' + titles[i] + '</a>');` with `.append()` accomplishes this, but the result is that with each hover over the same list item, the <a> tag is duplicated.

Comment: Okay, I see what you want, and you are correct that the trick is not to get it appended multiple times. You could add an if-statement in there, but I'd have to think about about that would be.

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/pKZ9U/5/) to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your check/append in `.hover()` functions will make it occur when there's mousein/mouseout:

```
$("#slideshow-nav li").hover(
    function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("activeSlide")) {
            var ind = $("#slideshow-nav li").index();
            $("#slideshow-nav li.activeSlide").append("<a href='#'>" + titles[ind] + "</a>");
        }
    }, 
    function () {
        if($("#slideshow-nav li:not(.activeSlide)")) {
            $("a").remove();
        }
    }
 );
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Now the title that appears on hover just needs to change. (So Title 1 has Title 1 next to it, Title 2 has Title 2 next to it, etc.) It's being called here `var ind = $("#slideshow-nav li").index();` and `$("#slideshow-nav li.activeSlide").append("<a href='#'>" + titles[ind] + "</a>");` but isn't calling the right index. I must have done it wrong.